# Creating JDBC connector source for interbase

Tags: curl, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, interbase

I am trying to create a JDBC connector for kafka using curl command. Please help me to correct this command.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json"  --data "{ \"name\": 
\"ib_connector\",\"config\": { \"connector.class\": \"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector\", \"tasks.max\": 1,
\"connection.url\": \"jdbc:interbase://ip:3050;Database=TEST2;user=SYSDBA;password=masterkey\",\"mode\": \"timestamp+incrementing\", \"incrementing.column.name\": \"id\",\"timestamp.column.name\": \"modified\", \"topic.prefix\": \"test-interbase-\", \"poll.interval.ms\": 1000 } }"
http://localhost:8083/connectors
```

Shows the following error in command prompt

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

I am running through docker-compose.yml file as this

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:${CONFLUENT_VERSION}
    networks:
      - kafka
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 39999

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:${CONFLUENT_VERSION}
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    networks:
      - kafka
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 49999

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:${CONFLUENT_VERSION}
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
    networks:
      - kafka
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL: zookeeper:2181
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry

  connect:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:${CONFLUENT_VERSION}
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
    networks:
      - kafka
    volumes:
      - ${KAFKA_CONNECT_JARS_PATH}:/etc/kafka-connect/jars
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'kafka:9092'
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: connect
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-connect-group
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-configs
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_OFFSET_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS: 10000
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-offsets
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-status
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: '/usr/share/java,/etc/kafka-connect/jars'

networks:
  kafka:
    driver: bridge
```

kafka is running and i have used the command `docker-compose up -d` to run it and i got success message. I am running it on windows.Below is the status of containers.

When i run docker-compose up -d it is shown as Kafka_manager is starting. But as soon as i check the status it shows exit 255. Does it affect saving configuration to port 8083.

[image]

What could be the reason. Kafka-connect is active and running in port 8083. Please help

Comment: What version of Kafka are you using? How are you running Kafka Connect? Are you using Confluent CLI, or another method?

Comment: I am using docker to run kafka.

Comment: Can you update your question to include how you're running it? Are you using Docker Compose? Is Kafka Connect definitely running? Have you expose the port to your host machine?

Comment: Here's a simple example of a Docker Compose for running Kafka + Kafka Connect https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/master/cos/docker-compose.yml

Comment: I have edited the question. And i have used almost same docker compose file as in this link. The docker compose is running and the port is in same machine.

Comment: You say "Kafka is active and running in port 8083", but it's **Kafka Connect**  that should be on port 8083. Can you update your question with the output of `docker-compose ps` ?

Comment: You aren't required to use curl, by the way. Postman could be a better option, but it still won't return a result if things aren't actually running

Comment: @RobinMoffatt Kafka Connect is in port 8083 not kafka . Thank you

Comment: Please don't post screenshots for console output. Text is much easier to read :)

Comment: I'm ignoring Kafka Manager etc because that's not going to affect Kafka Connect. Let's focus on Kafka Connect. What's the output of `curl -s http://localhost:8083` ? And what's the output of `docker-compose logs kafka-connect | grep "Kafka Connect started"` ? If you view the full contents of the Connect worker (`docker-compose logs kafka-connect`) are there any errors?

Comment: @robin The command `curl -s http://localhost:8083` didn't show anything as output. The command `compose logs kafka-connect` showed UnknownHostException for Zookeeper. Now it is alright and only have warnings.  And i tried to run curl turning off firewall. That also didn't work.

Comment: @RobinMoffatt Sorry for posting screenshots :)

Comment: Can you post your _actual_ Docker Compose file that you're using? Either update your question, or put it on gist.github.com or similar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184876/discussion-between-bommu-and-robin-moffatt).

Comment: I have posted the docker-compose file in github. Herw is the link. https://gist.github.com/Bommu03/76fd0b30ba1438c9a8fdd7d555c3fa5d. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

kafka runs on 9092 while connect worker on 8083.

you are posting configuration on 8083 so make sure you have worker up and running.